# Using multiple authentication providers giving error in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have user details maintained in different internal_users and external_users DB tables. For that I am creating two different authentication providers, for various flow of authentication. Below is the code that is giving error:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        // securedEnabled = true,
        // jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private internalUserDetailsServiceImpl internalUserDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private externalUserDetailsServiceImpl externalUserDetailsServiceImpl;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
      "/api/auth/**",
      "/swagger-resources/**",
      "/swagger-ui/**",
      "/v3/api-docs",
      "/v2/api-docs",
      "/webjars/**"
    };

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider externalUserauthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider externalUserAuthProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        externalUserAuthProvider.setUserDetailsService(externalUserDetailsServiceImpl);
        externalUserAuthProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

        return externalUserAuthProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider internalUserAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider internalUserAuthProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        internalUserAuthProvider.setUserDetailsService(internalUserDetailsServiceImpl);
        internalUserAuthProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

        return internalUserAuthProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.authenticationProvider(internalUserAuthProvider())
         .authenticationProvider(externalUserAuthProvider());

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

I am getting below issue:

> Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError

On further debugging I found that the controller, where below code is used, `authenticationManager` is showing an error as shown in image attached

```
Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authDTO.getUserName(), authDTO.getPassword()));
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

[image]

On commenting out any one of the authentication providers, the code is working, but not working with both authentication providers. Below is working code with one authentication provider

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        // securedEnabled = true,
        // jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private internalUserDetailsServiceImpl internalUserDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private externalUserDetailsServiceImpl externalUserDetailsServiceImpl;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
      "/api/auth/**",
      "/swagger-resources/**",
      "/swagger-ui/**",
      "/v3/api-docs",
      "/v2/api-docs",
      "/webjars/**"
    };

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

   /*@Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider externalUserauthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider externalUserAuthProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        externalUserAuthProvider.setUserDetailsService(externalUserDetailsServiceImpl);
        externalUserAuthProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

        return externalUserAuthProvider;
    } */

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider internalUserAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider internalUserAuthProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        internalUserAuthProvider.setUserDetailsService(internalUserDetailsServiceImpl);
        internalUserAuthProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

        return internalUserAuthProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.authenticationProvider(internalUserAuthProvider());
         //.authenticationProvider(externalUserAuthProvider());

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Any clue what exactly I am missing.

Comment: I found the solution in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73322338/spring-security-5-7-multiple-authentication-provider-without-websecurityconfig

Comment: why are you using a JWT as a session, there is no such implementation because its insecure to do so, and you just dont care and write a custom jwtfilter

Comment: @Toerktumlare   I am using jwt token for all api calls rather than using  session-based authentication , as we have different microservices. What the best alternative can you suggest apart from jwt for maintaining sessions. Thanks.

Comment: no, you are using a token as a session instead of using a cookie as a session. You should be reading the spring recommendations for SPA based apps https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297 which goes through all patterns. Handing out JWTs to browser makes so you cant explicitly log out the user, you also run the risk of the JWT token to be stolen. So please do not invent your own security, my guess is that you have followed some poorly written tutorial from someone that has no clue of how security works.

Comment: @Toerktumlare but I have service to service integerations, mobile app as integerations. Web based logins are secondary in my case. Mainly logins are via mobile apps

Comment: a mobile app is a client like a browser. read the recommendations, but if you wish to build something insecure, go ahead, as long as you are aware of the risks, which you dont seem to be.